# Directed to undirected graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Given an arbitrary directed graph `DG` in python, is it possible to elegantly make it an undirected one? (This is all in terms of the networkx library).

I was trying to compute some statistics like average clustering, number of triangles etc. However these all are defined for the undirected graphs, so I was wondering if it is trivial to convert the directed graph into an undirected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
H = G.to_undirected()
```

See the [Networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.to_undirected.html).